# How can I plot a 3d graph with data points in Maple?

Tags: maple

I am trying to plot this data on Maple as 3D scatter plot and surface plot:[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Cut-and-paste format of the data:

> Pressure(Bar) Temp (K)    k (/Ms)
>   19.02          311.15         6.83E+08
>   18.64          307.05         5.94E+08
>   18.54          304.65         6.33E+08
>   20.5           301.15         5.56E+08
>   31.07          298.15         4.2588E+08
>   32.64          304.65         4.4338E+08
>   30.01          311.15         4.4338E+08
>   28.04          300.23         4.2588E+08
>   40.46          298.5          6.84E+07
>   40.34          304.65         1.1050E+08
>   39.36          308.6          8.2132E+07
>   39.18          310.81         8.8382E+07
>   50.17          300.75     1.3934E+08
>   51.03          302.63     5.7132E+07
>   51.39          304.55     9.2228E+07
>   52.65          311.2      1.4588E+08
>   51.14          308.45         9.7997E+07
>   60.66          311.75     1.4878E+08
>   59.11          308.15     1.3838E+08
>   59.94          304.65     1.6723E+08
>   58.1           302.95     1.1765E+08
>   58.27          301.85     1.3838E+08
>   57.84          300.75     1.4588E+08

Comment: It would help if your data were in a format that could be cut-and-pasted.

Comment: @CarlLove The data is in excel format, so yes it can be cut-and-pasted. Anything else besides that?

Comment: I meant that I would like to cut-and-paste it right out of the post.

Comment: Oh I don't know how I can post it in a cut-and-paste format, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Which column is considered the dependent variable?

Comment: Okay, I got the data. Thanks. I guess Acer just typed it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the example worksheet on interpolation and smoothing ( http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=examples%2fInterpolation_and_Smoothing )

At bottom, I've also included a simple method using inverse-distance and weighted averaging (which is fast, but which extrapolates poorly).

Sorry, for some reason I am unable to attach images of the plots right now.

I have used your third column as the dependent data, but it should be straightforward to change that. Just make sure that the dependent data is the 3rd column of the Matrix formed like, say, `<P|T|M>`.

```
restart:

P:=Vector([19.02,18.64,18.54,20.5,31.07,32.64,30.01,28.04,40.46,
           40.34,39.36,39.18,50.17,51.03,51.39,52.65,51.14,60.66,
           59.11,59.94,58.1,58.27,57.74],
          datatype=float[8]):
T:=Vector([311.15,307.05,304.65,301.15,298.15,304.64,311.15,300.23,
           298.5,304.65,308.6,310.81,300.75,302.63,304.55,311.2,
           308.45,311.75,308.15,304.65,302.95,301.85,300.65],
          datatype=float[8]):
M:=Vector([6.83,5.94,6.33,5.56,4.2588,4.4338,4.4338,4.2588,
           0.684,1.1050,0.82132,0.88382,1.3934,0.57132,
           0.92228,1.4588,0.97997,1.4878,1.3838,1.6723,
           1.1765,1.3838,1.4588],datatype=float[8])*1E8:
```

First, one can construct the basic 3D point plot from the data. Some version of the point plot (with some shading scheme) may or may not be displayed alongside the various surfaces constructed below.

```
plots:-pointplot3d( <P|T|M>, symbolsize=20, axes=box );
```

Next, a simple triangular mesh can be used to interpolate linearly between the points.

```
Ptriang := plots:-surfdata( <P|T|M>, view=0..7e8, source=irregular ):

plots:-display( Ptriang,
                plots:-pointplot3d(<P|T|M>,symbolsize=20,color=red),
                axes=box );
```

Another approach is to smooth the data. This may not produce great results for such a small amount of data. There are several adjustable options for the method. It is not fast.

```
Ploess := Statistics:-ScatterPlot3D( <P|T|M>, view=0..7e8,
                                     lowess, fitorder=2,
                                     bandwidth=1/2, rule=1,
                                     grid=[50,50], axes=box ):

plots:-display( Ploess,
                plots:-pointplot3d(<P|T|M>,symbolsize=20,color=red) );
```

Another possible approach is to to use weighted average (weighted by distance or some metric). Below, a black-box procedure `ff` is created which takes any p-t point and returns the computed m-value. (A better scheme for this would be interpolation over Voronoi cells using so-called natural neighbors and radial basis functions, but I have only unfinished code for that at present.)

```
f := proc(x::float, y::float,
       N::integer,
       X::Vector(datatype=float[8]),
       Y::Vector(datatype=float[8]),
       Z::Vector(datatype=float[8]),
       p::integer, R::float)
 local i::integer,j::integer,res::float,innerres::float,dist::float;
 innerres:=0.0;
 for j from 1 to N do
     dist:=sqrt((x-X[j])^2+(y-Y[j])^2);
     innerres:=innerres+(max(0, abs(R-dist))/(R*dist))^p;
 end do;
 res:=0.0;
 for i from 1 to N do
   dist:=sqrt((x-X[i])^2+(y-Y[i])^2);
   res := res + Z[i]*(max(0, abs(R-dist))/(R*dist))^p/innerres;
 end do;
 res;
end proc:

try
  ff:=Compiler:-Compile(f);
catch:
  ff:=proc(x,y,N,P,T,M,p,R) evalhf(f(x,y,N,P,T,M,p,R)); end proc;
end try:
```

We can query procedure `ff` at any (p,t) point.

```
ff(40.2, 304.7, 23, P, T, M, 3, 4.0);
```

which produces,

```
                                      8
                1.10586391484649837 10
```

And `ff` can now be used directly in the `plot3d` command,

```
Pinvdist := plot3d('ff'(p, t, 23, P, T, M, 3, 20.0),
                   p=min(P)..max(P), t=min(T)..max(T),
                   numpoints = 900, view=0..7e8):

plots:-display( Pinvdist,
                plots:-pointplot3d(<P|T|M>,symbolsize=20,color=red),
                axes=box );
```

Comment: I tried by copying and pasting your code on Maple but it is not working.

Comment: I used Maple 17. Which part causes the problem? Be careful not to try and execute the one bit of output in my posted code (the result of calling `ff` on an example p-t point). Which version are you using?

Comment: I typed this code: Ptriang := plots:-surfdata( <P|T|R>, view=0..7e8, source=irregular ); 

Maple says there's an error: Error, missing operator or `;`

Comment: My code produces 4 plots: a 3D point plot, a linear interpolation with triangular (Delaunay) mesh (needs Maple 16 or higher), a loess smoothed surface, and a surface using weighted averages. The code is plaintext 1D input, though it may work also as 2D input. But of course remove the small included output fragment from calling `ff` at a point. I'm not sure whether your error stems from the last line, or from earlier. Another syntax for using the 3-column 23x3 Matrix is, `plots:-surfdata(Matrix([P,T,M]), view=0..7e8,source=irregular,axes=boxed)`. You haven't yet said which version you had.

Comment: The options for lowess smoothing are tricky at best, and perhaps problematic with so few data points. Another possible option subset for `ScatterPlot3D` might be, say, `lowess, fitorder=0, bandwidth=1/3, rule=1` and retain the earlier `view`, `grid`, and `axes` options's values.

Comment: I am using Maple 17.

Comment: Hey man, it worked! Thanks for the help.